# cast/transform BitArray to BitVector32

Tags: c#

Is it possible to transform a BitArray to a BitVector32 without having to go:

BitArray > int > BitVector32(int)

This obviously does not work:

```
var bitArray = new BitArray(32);
bitArray[1] = true;

var bitVector = new BitVector32(0);
for(var c = 0; c < bitArray.Length; c++)
{
    bitVector[c] = bitArray[c];
}
```

I understand that BitVector32 is a structure and should therefore be immutable. Does this mean that I always have to determine the integer first to perform the 'cast/transformation'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that BitVector32 is a structure and should therefore be immutable.

This is a common myth. Classes can be immutable and structs can be mutable. `BitVectr32` is indeed a mutable struct. The real problem in your code is that you assume that `BitVector32` indexer matches `BitArray` (or array, list etc.) indexer. However, the `BitVector32` indexer is declared as follows

```
public bool this[int bit] { get; set; }
```

and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3ddh1xt(v=vs.110).aspx) states

> Gets or sets the state of the bit flag indicated by the specified **mask**.

So the working code would be like this

```
var bitVector = new BitVector32(0);
for (var c = 0; c < bitArray.Length; c++)
    bitVector[1 << c] = bitArray[c];
```

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I had a look at a few mask examples and they did not make sense. Your example, however, is great!